# Facebook tab not working in IE, works on website URL

Tags: facebook, tabs

I've created this facebook tab, and for some reason it will not work in IE once implemented into facebook. It DOES work on the website url where it is placed. The url is: https://www.enterprisebanking.com/assets/fb-products/

The tab works great in every browser except for IE. In IE, the entire middle section is missing and the tabs are unable to be clicked on.

Here's a screenshot of how the tab looks in IE: http://grab.by/s9Qu

Any advice is appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You have a console.log in https://www.enterprisebanking.com/assets/fb-products/js/tabs.js this will cause it to break in IE.